# Event emitter doesn't work properly after first request

Tags: node.js, express, events, event-handling, eventemitter

I have a basic controller in my express.js application. And I try to execute a certain service that fetch mock data after small delay. This service is inherited from EventEmitter, and emits `SUCCESS` event after the data was received.

Here is my controller:

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const GetAllUsers = require('../GetAllUsers');
const getAllUsers = new GetAllUsers();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  getAllUsers
    .on('SUCCESS', (users) => {
      res
        .status(200)
        .json({ users });
    })
    .on('ERROR', next);

  getAllUsers.execute();
});

module.exports = router;
```

And service:

```js
const EventEmitter = require('events');

class GetAllUsers extends EventEmitter {
  async execute() {
    const data = [{ id: 1, name: 'user 1' }, { id: 2, name: 'user 2' }];

    try {
      const users = await new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve(data);
        }, 1000);
      })

      this.emit('SUCCESS', users);
    } catch (error) {
      this.emit('ERROR', error);
    }
  }
}

module.exports = GetAllUsers;
```

The problem is that when I enter on the `/users` path for the first time I actually get a list of users. But when I try the second time and subsequent, I get the following error:

```
Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:471:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/home/debian/dev/sandbox/emitterTest/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:767:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/home/debian/dev/sandbox/emitterTest/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (/home/debian/dev/sandbox/emitterTest/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:267:15)
    at GetAllUsers.getAllUsers.on (/home/debian/dev/sandbox/emitterTest/routes/users.js:12:10)
    at GetAllUsers.emit (events.js:187:15)
    at GetAllUsers.execute (/home/debian/dev/sandbox/emitterTest/GetAllUsers.js:14:12)
```

As far as I understand, headers are set somewhere before I send my response.

And when I trying to implement my controller without emitter, everything works fine:

```js
router.get('/', async function(req, res, next) {
  const data = [{ id: 1, name: 'user 1' }, { id: 2, name: 'user 2' }];

  const users = await new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(data);
    }, 1000);
  })

  res
    .status(200)
    .json({ users });
});
```

How can this problem be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because every time you make a request, you run your router function:

```
function(req, res, next) {
  getAllUsers 
    .on('SUCCESS', (users) => { //subscribe to event every time
      res
        .status(200)
        .json({ users });
    })
    .on('ERROR', next);

  getAllUsers.execute();
}
```

You got subscribed to those event and run it once. At the time, you made a second request, you got 2 subscribers : from previous request, and from current. And then, the `execute()` function fires the event. So there's 2 functions executed at a time, and one of them, **tries to send response again**, but that is impossible, therefore it causes an error.

If those event emitter is really needed, you can subscribe to fire event only once by using the `getAllUsers.once` function.

Comment: Thank you! That was a helpful answer.